# Can you determine a set of values from a set of sums?

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the following problem:

There is an vector $A$ (which you will not see) of $n$ positive integers. You are given the set of sums of the (contiguously indexed) subvectors of $A$. For example, say

$$A = (3,2,1,2)$$

The subvectors are $(3),(2),(1),(2), (3,2), (2,1), (1,2),(3,2,1), (2,1,2),(3,2,1,2)$.
We would be given the sums $\{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8\}$.  Let us call this set of sums $f(A)$.

Is it always possible to uniquely determine the set of integers in $A$ from $f(A)$ and $n$?

---

The answer turns out to be **no**. I posted a followup to [When does a set of sums uniquely determine a set of values?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2956925/when-does-a-set-of-sums-uniquely-determine-a-set-of-values) .

Comment: I understand that the vector is ordered, while the set of sums is not. So B=(2,1,2,3) is different from A, but f(A)=f(B). In this case, the answer is no.

Comment: @toliveira While this is true, I do think the question is a bit more interesting if we assume the subvectors are not ordered.

Comment: I accidentally read the question wrong initially, and I am interested in the version where you get a *multiset* of sums instead of just a set. Did you consider that question @felipa? Edit: and possibly you also want to reconstruct the multiset $A$, rather than just its 'set version'.

Comment: @toliveira The question is about determining the set of integers in $A$ which is $\{1,2,3\}$.  Your $B$ has the same set of integers. So in your case I don't think we know the answer is no.

Comment: What are "some linear operations"? This is not obvious to me at all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No: both $(1, 1, 2, 2)$ and $(1, 1, 1, 3)$ give you the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$.

Comment: These perfect dice!

Comment: You can't? What about $(1, 3)$?

Comment: Yes, you can make $4$ with the second vector, using the last two entries.

Comment: @MeesdeVries You can take out 1 from both vectors and it still is a counterexample

Comment: How confusing... something got updated since my comment.  Nice counterexample! Thank you.

Comment: I posted a followup question to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2956925/when-does-a-set-of-sums-uniquely-determine-a-set-of-values

Answer (score 6):

The answer is no.

Take the following subvectors:

$$A = (1, 1, 3)$$$$B = (1,2,2)$$It's easy to see that both vectors have a sum vector of $[1,2,3,4,5]$.

Comment: The reconstruction also gets $n$, the length of the original vector.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Nope, the vectors have to be the same length. If not, $(1,1,1)$ and $(1,2)$ would be a counter example.