# When does a set of sums uniquely determine a set of values?

Tags: combinatorics

This is a follow up to [a question about determining the set of values from a set of sums.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2956667/can-you-determine-a-set-of-values-from-a-set-of-sums)

We consider the following setup:

Consider a vector $A$ (which you will not see) of $n$ positive integers. You are given the set of sums of the (contiguously indexed) subvectors of $A$. For example, say

$$A = (3,2,1,2)$$

The subvectors are $(3),(2),(1),(2), (3,2), (2,1), (1,2),(3,2,1), (2,1,2),(3,2,1,2)$.
We would be given the sums $\{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8\}$.  Let us call this set of sums $f(A)$.

It turns out it is *not* always possible to uniquely determine the set of integers in $A$ from the pair $(f(A), n)$? For example:

$$A = (1,1,3)$$
and
$$B = (1,2,2)$$

both give the same set of sums $f(A) = f(B) = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

However in some cases it *is* possible. For example, if $n=3$ and $f(C) = \{1,2,3,5,6\}$ then we know that $\operatorname{set}(C) = \{1, 2, 3\}$.

This raises the following question:

> Is it possible to characterise which pairs $(f(X), n)$ uniquely 
>   determine the set of values in the array $X$?

Comment: Maybe it suffices to know that in the sum, there exist a one or a zero???

Comment: @user7427029 I don’t quite understand your comment. Zero isn’t allowed as all the values in the arrays are positive. Also there is a 1 in the set of sums for both A and B in my example so that idea doesn’t work.

Comment: Observations: $a := \min_{c\in f(X)} c \in set(X)$ and $S := \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i = \max_{c\in f(X)} c$.
Maybe one can conclude $a = X_1$ or $a = X_n$, if $S - a \in set(X)$. And then this can be applied recursively?

Comment: I should not write comments nightly. I thought of something like what @Frozn proposes. Two conjectures / ideas (I'm in a hurry): The question asks for something like the fundamental theorem of arithmetic concerning addition. Zeckendorf's theorem may help.

Comment: You may find useful results in links from a search for _finite radon transform_ : https://www.google.com/search?q=finite+radon+transform&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1

Comment: @EthanBolker Can you say more about this connection? I don’t see it all at the moment sadly.

Comment: @felipa I can't say more without thinking a lot more about your problem. The suggestion comes from the fact that the (finite) Radon transform is all about recovering the contents of a set of numbers when you know some sums of subsets.

Comment: minimum in the set of outputs is the minimum in the vector, last number in output tells you vector sum. diving by n gives the weighted average.difference between last and second last would give you a hint to your first example, their difference is an element.